# vtiger Call to a member function Execute() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\database\PearDatabase

Tags: php, xampp, vtiger

I am installing vtiger,

when i open the index page,

i got this error:

> **Fatal error:** Call to a member function Execute() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\database\PearDatabase.php **on line 357**

i opened the PearDatabase.php file, and I found this:

```
if($this->avoidPreparedSql || empty($params)) {
            $sql = $this->convert2Sql($sql, $params);
            $result = $this->database->Execute($sql);
        } else {
            $result = $this->database->Execute($sql, $params);
        }
```

the line 357 is:

```
$result = $this->database->Execute($sql);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed vtiger once locally, you have to clean cookies in your brower of your local vtiger domain.
That should fix your problem, what a amazing bug it is!

Comment: one of the worst tools ever, they don't have any support, glad i got red of it

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed all the pre-requisites:

Pre-requisites [from here](http://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/administrators/installation.html):

- Apache 2.1+
- MySQL 5.1+ (default storage engine = InnoDB)
- PHP 5.2+, 5.3

  - php-imap
  - php-curl
  - php-xml
  - max_memory (min. 256MB)
  - max_execution_time (min. 60 seconds)
  - error_reporting (E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED)
- Hardware: 4 GB RAM, 250 GB Disk (for file attachments)

The error is suggesting that it can't work out what to do with the back end database.

Answer (score 1):

You will receive this error when installing vTiger if your `session_save_path()` is not writable by your web server user.

In my case, my 'session_save_path' was `/var/lib/php/7.1/session` and was owned by `root`. I am using Nginx so I executed the following command to resolve my issue:

```
sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /var/lib/php/7.1/session
```

If you are using Apache, you would execute the following command to resolve your issue:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/php/7.1/session
```

The information entered into the vTiger wizard is saved to `$_SESSION` as you navigate through the installation steps.

When the 'session_save_path' is owned by `root` rather than the web server user, the session data is not saved between function `Step5()` and function `Step6()` in `modules/Install/views/Index.php`. So when the `config.inc.php` file is created by the wizard, all the configuration data you entered into the form is not written to `config.inc.php` since your data was not saved in `$_SESSION` between the requests. This can be fixed by changing the permissions on your 'session_save_path' to be writable by the web server user.

You can find your session.save_path in your `php.ini` file or your `www.conf` file if you are using php-fpm:

```
/etc/php-fpm-7.1.d/www.conf:php_value[session.save_path]    = /var/lib/php/7.1/session
```

This unhelpful error is actually because your database connection is unsuccessful in file `include/database/PearDatabase.php` in function `connect()` since all the database variables are empty.

Hope this helps.